# Search page loop banner image issue

Tags: loop, search

In Header file I have added

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
<img src='banner.jpg' />
<?php }  ?>
```

`
But in Search page the banner is loop equal to number of results. How can i avoid this. I want to show banner just one time in search page

Answer (score 1):

You have the header inside the Loop, so of course it prints once for each result. Put that outside the Loop proper.

```
if (have_posts()) { ?>
  <img src='banner.jpg' /><?php
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    // print contents
  }
}
```

Also, [don't use relative URLs in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101215/21376). You are in for all kinds of headache if you try.

Comment: Is have->posts() a thing or do you mean have_posts() ? :)

Comment: Fixed it. Just a typo.