# Paginate pages with dynamic query

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, pagination

I have a wordpress page that has a series of listings and a searchbox at the top. The search allows the user to filter posts by creating a custom WP_Query object based on what they selected. I am wondering if there is a way I can have this be paginated so that there aren't hundreds of results displaying on the page.

Basically I have an if statement to check if the form is submitted which then populates the selected fields into an array and passes it to the meta_query

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
          'post_type' => 'business',
          'post_status' => 'publish', 
          'taxonomy' => 'business-type',
          'business-type' => 'attraction',
          'posts_per_page' => 15,
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'meta_query' => $arrays,
          'paged' => $paged
        ));
    }else{
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'business',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'taxonomy' => 'business-type',
        'business-type' => 'attraction',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged
       ));
```

The I loop through the query using `while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();`

and after endwhile; I have my pagination

```
if($the_query->max_num_pages>1){?>
    <div class="pagination">
    <?php
      if ($paged > 1) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged -1); //prev link ?>"><</a>
      <?php }
      for($i=1;$i<=$the_query->max_num_pages;$i++){
        if($paged==$i){?>
          <span class="current"><?php echo $i; ?></span>
        <?php }else{?>
          <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . $i; ?>" class="inactive"><?php echo $i;?></a>
        <?php
      }
    }
    if($paged < $the_query->max_num_pages){?>
        <a href="<?php echo '?paged=' . ($paged + 1); //next link ?>">></a>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Almost certainly "yes", but post your code please.

Comment: Edit: Added my code

Answer (score 1):

I was going to create my own question and answer it, but this looks as good a place as any. The way I solved this, is by using $_SESSION. Keep in mind I am using infinite-scroll, so I can tell when the page is being fetched via ajax as opposed to being actually navigated to in the browser.

So here's the steps/pseudo-code:

1. Clear Session Variables
2. Run "Default" loop and get html
3. User filters results -> get results from new loop
4. Set Session Variables so page knows which loops to run
5. User scrolls down -> get results from current page, but for next page
6. This page displays a loop conditionally based on the session variables
7. ??????
8. Profit

I would just post my code, but it is pretty large so I'd rather not. If you can't figure it out, let me know though and I will post the skeleton of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, you are not passing any `meta` parameters through to the pagination function. You will need to create links like :

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink(). '?paged=' . ($paged + 1) . '&meta_key='.$something.'&meta_value='.$somethingelse; //next link ?>">Link Text</a>
```

I assume your are processing that meta information for your initial query somewhere in order to populate `$arrays` but unless you pass that information along to the subsequent queries you will end up with the default search on pages 2 and on and not a paginated list restricted to the selected item.

Note that I added `get_permalink` to your link. You were using a relative URL and [those will cause a lot of heartache in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101215/21376).

You might also look into [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) instead of rolling your own pagination. It is handy.... not necessary, but handy.

Comment: I will definitely add get_permalink(), thanks for catching that. I never thought about passing my meta key/values to the link itself. The main problem with that is my search form has checkboxes so I am actually passing the meta_query an array that contains all fields of the form some(checkboxes) being arrays themselves.

Comment: But you are not passing that form data when someone clicks a link. The initial form submission works, I assume, but you need to pass that data along with the pagination links-- you _have to_ if you want the pagination to work, unless you use something like `$_SESSION` or cookies which are more complicated solutions. You can pass arrays through a `GET` string, just use square brackets-- `&meta_value[]=value1&meta_value[]=value2` and so on.

Comment: And you are not just shoving that form data into the query unprocessed are you? That is a dangerous thing to do if you are.

Comment: I will give this a go and see what happens. Currently I pass an array of fields like so: `$arrays=array(
                array(
                  'key' => 'attraction_type',
                  'value' => $attraction_type,
                  'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ), ... more arrays` where the variable corresponds to the field value. Then I query the posts and filter out the ones that don't have the selected checkbox amenities. Previously I passed the checkbox array to my meta_query array and it weighed the loadtime down and crashed the site.