# problem with ajax contact forms

Tags: contact

I have been having trouble with contact forms. They work find in an html site but whenever I try them in WordPress, they fail. I have narrowed down the issue to the url: setting. For example

```
  $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: str,
        success: function (msg)
        {
```

WordPress is unable to find the contact.php file. I found that if I put in the full url to the file, then it works. Do you know how I can fix this without having to do that?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101215/21376

Comment: ok, but how do you use a php function is a js file? I don't know enough js. I guess I need to look for the equivalent js code

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) instead of trying to load files directly. Even if you got that file to load, if it uses any WordPress functions it wouldn't work anyway. If you load a theme file directly none of the WordPress Core will boot and so none of the function will be defined.

The Codex article should be sufficient for getting that working but this site is full of questions and answers concerning it. [I have written about 30](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:21376%20Ajax%20API) at this point. See if you can't get started and then refine the question if you run into trouble.