# Single Page Wordpress CSS and JS links

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, themes

i got a custom template with blog post in it...

In my header.php, inside the `<head>` i have my links like this ...

```
<link href="http://www.mysite.com/css/design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

those links are working in my custom template.. by using

`<?php get_header(); ?>`

All blog post in my custom page are there.. no layout problems.

But when i click one of the post. my layout is broken. and when i checked it via Inspect Element. the link is like this

```
<link href="http://www.mysite.com/blog/css/design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/blog/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

*** EDIT ***  from the answers below, above is my original question, anyway my problem is still the same.

I added this to my functions.php  and removed the links on my header.php 
also i copied the files inside the wordpress folder called links...

`/httpdocs/blog/wp-content/themes/myblog/links`

```
    // Get Links 

    function theme_scripts_styles() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/links/design.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts1', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/links/cufon-yui.js', array(), '1.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/links/232MKSD_200.font.js', array(), '1.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts3', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/links/232MKSDB_400.font.js', array(), '1.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts4', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/links/fonts.js', array(), '1.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts5', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/links/OpenSans_400.font.js', array(), '1.0', true );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts6', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/links/OpenSansSB_600.font.js', array(), '1.0', true );



}

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts_styles' );
```

Comment: That is a significant edit. How much have you changed int he code in response to answers below? Is the problem still the same as when you first posted?

Comment: I'm joining to the @s_ha_dum's question, does it work now or you still have problem?

Comment: same problem..  even though i already followed the answers below.

Comment: another thing that comes to mind is: have you made the call to `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();` ? Respectively in header.php and footer.php.

Comment: Yes, they are in my header and footer files. my wp_head(); is located just above the </head> and my wp_footer(); is located just above the </body>

Comment: Ok thanks, did you get some errors with firebug|console web|etc?

Comment: yeah it couldn't locate the files.. the URL changes to <link href="http://www.mysite.com/blog/this-is-my-post/css/design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  when i click on the single post page

Comment: its my .htaccess file ... i deleted it. then went to permalinks and saved it again. it fixed the problem.. so all answers here are correct even my code above is i think also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are using relative URLs in your `header.php` file. That would explain the difference in the paths. (It is probably differnt on archive pages too, right?) Don't do that. [Relative URLs do not work well in a WordPress context.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101215/21376) Generally, you want to use `get_permalink()`, `site_url()`, `home_url()`, etc. to create absolute URLs. For the template files you want [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) and [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

I am guessing that you are also not registering and enqueueing the stylesheets and scripts.

See:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: Hi, i edited my question.. please see the code.