# Relative URLs within site

Tags: urls, links, paths

I want to link to a page inside a website so the url I want to link to is this:

http://www.example.org/about-us/team

when I set a link like that:

```
<a href="about-us/team">Our Team</a>
```

It doesnt work. I get to the site: http://about-us/team

Is there a solution to that?
The reason why is because after the Website is finished it will go online under a different domain.

best regards

Comment: Don't use relative URLS. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101215/21376 And: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111680/21376

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a slash to the beginning of path

```
<a href="/about-us/team">Our Team</a>
```